# gravityform - method Get instead of Post - error 301

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I'm in trouble with gravity form.
In the home page (http://www.nature-experience-group.com) when I fill and send the form to receive the brochure, the form is not send, I don'thave any log in wordpress, neither receive any mail (notification is ok).

In the console I can see that it is a GET that is send, and receive a 301 error : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSp6U.jpg

I don't have any problem with other form in the site (like here http://www.nature-experience-group.com/contact-agence-de-voyage-en-ligne/)

I don't have any problem meither with the same form in an other page.

Is it because I have two forms in the home page ?

Comment: where are you sending `Get` request? it's redirect issue on the image you provided

Comment: Hi Samvel and thanks for your answer.
I just found the solution this morning, forcing the post method in the HTML code.